# Why is my nginx server dropping post request bodies?

Tags: php, nginx, post

My nginx server has recently started losing the data sent in post requests.  I have read that this is due to redirects, mostly from http to https and vice versa.  The solutions I have found involve returning a 308 (permanent redirect) instead to preserve post data. To test this, I created a simple php script that just vardumps $_GET and $_POST.  However this has not solved the issue of the post requests dropping completely.  below is my nginx server config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certifcate /path/to/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/key.key;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    root /path/to/files;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name sub.domain.us;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /path/to/files;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name sub.domain.us;
    location / {
        return 308 https://sub.domain.us$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Any insights into why the request bodies are still dropping would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not "weird nginx redirects", it is the fact that the commonly-used 301 and 302 redirects cause clients to drop the POST contents and reissue the request as GET. This is part of the HTTP spec. 307 and 308 should be used to keep POST requests intact, but this also causes the full POST, including sending all data, to happen _twice_. That said, the config you've posted looks fine and shouldn't cause that. You should post more information about reproducing the issue, ideally without relying on a browser extension.

Comment: Some how, curl is able to properly complete the request, but Apache HttpClient and Postman arent.